# Implement a colored frame around graph tiles (panel bokeh) (holoViz bokeh)

Tags: python, bokeh, panel, pandas-bokeh, holoviz-panel

How can I let bokeh draw a colored border (frame) around the graph tile? Some graph tiles have to be graphically highlighted against the other graphs and the customer therefore wants to have a colored border / colored frame around some graph tiles. Unfortunately, I did not find anything to it in the documentation on Holoviz bokeh.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards

Comment: Can you explain, preferably with an annotated screenshot, what you mean by a graph tile? One plot in a grid of similar plots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a border around a title by updating the `Title` annotation manually, or creating a new one and adding it to your `Figure`.

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models.annotations import Title
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import row

# Use your own Title annotation
p1 = figure(height=250, width=400)
p1.line([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1, 3])
p1.title = Title(
    text='hello world!', text_font_size='16pt', 
    border_line_color='red', border_line_width=3
)

# OR configure the existing one:
p2 = figure(height=250, width=400)
p2.line([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1, 3])
p2.title.text = 'hello world again!'
p2.title.border_line_color = 'green'
p2.title.border_line_width = 3
p2.title.text_font_size = '16pt'


show(row([p1, p2]))
```

[image]